# Does Shelob make Legendary Food?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Shelob, Child of Ungoliant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shelob%2C%20Child%20of%20Ungoliant) has the ability

> Whenever another creature dealt damage this turn by a Spider you controlled dies, create a token that's a copy of that creature, except it's a Food artifact with "2, Tap, Sacrifice this artifact: You gain 3 life," and it loses all other card types.

According to the rules text, "loses all other card types" includes subtypes. However, since "Legendary" is a supertype, does that mean that the Food token *does* become Legendary if it comes from a Legendary creature dying?

Comment: Note that even if the food token is legendary, it still retains the *name* of the creature it copied, so you would only face a legend-rule conflict if you have a *second* legendary food token of the same name.

Comment: Not just food, I believe - if I happen to have a copy of the same creature then I have to choose which one sticks around, right?

Comment: Yep, that's correct; 704.5j says "if two or more *legendary permanents* with the same name are controlled by the same player, that player chooses one of them, and the rest are put into their owners' graveyards." Nothing in there that those permanents have to also be the same type(s).

Comment: There's a reason mirror box is on my shelob maybe list

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, legendary. I base this on rule 205.4b, which

> 205.4b An object’s supertype is independent of its card type and subtype, even though some supertypes are closely identified with specific card types. **Changing an object’s card types or subtypes won’t change its supertypes**. Changing an object’s supertypes won’t change its card types or subtypes. When an object gains or loses a supertype, it retains any other supertypes it had.
> Example: An ability reads, “All lands are 1/1 creatures that are still lands.” If any of the affected lands were legendary, they are still legendary.

and given that a ruling on gatherer mentions "losing all other card types and subtypes", but not supertypes.

Comment: Nice! And then if someone animates their Snow-covered Forest and makes it their Ring-bearer I can have a Legendary Snow Basic Food token.

Answer (score 12):

### The token will be legendary food

> 205.4b An object’s supertype is independent of its card type and subtype, even though some supertypes are closely identified with specific card types. Changing an object’s card types or subtypes won’t change its supertypes.

Types and subtypes are inextricably linked, because each subtype belongs to a specific type, so changing the types necessarily wipes away the subtypes.  Supertypes are not linked in the same way, and changing types does not change the supertypes.